# Android/java: String url does not work in HttpGet(url)

Tags: java, android, url, encoding, text-files

I construct a string with a value I get from another activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

value = b.getString("bundledata");

url = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxx/apptextfiles/";
url += value;
url += ".txt";
```

so, the string url looks like http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxx/apptextfiles/LFC2.txt

Later on I try to read the textfile with HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url) - and the app crash. The strange thing is that if I write url = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxx/apptextfiles/LFC2.txt" it works fine, but not if I construct it like above. Actually, if I take the url value from eclipse and put it in a browser it changes to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxx/apptextfiles/%EF%BB%BFLFC2.txt - why?? It look like som strange encoding issue? The string value I get from the other activity is also taken from an online textfile. Anyone has a clue about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

It looks like the `value` field you have in your url string contains special characters -- `ï , » and ¿`

Thats the reason for your url getting encoded as you referenced. Use a hexeditor or something to make sure your textfile does not contain special characters.

Comment: I tried to check the string value with `encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8");` and encodedString is %EF%BB%BFLFC2. How do I 'strip' off those extra hidden %EF%BB%BF so I only end up with LFC2? :o)

Comment: You could simply strip the string of the first 3 characters by doing a substring. But you really should try to make sure your source of the string does not contain special characters.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll just use `encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8").substring(9);` for now, it works. I just can't figure out where that extra encoding comes from..